# What does the linearity of a derivative mean?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

What does the linearity of the $n$th order derivative of a dependent variable $y$ with respect to, say, time $t$ mean?

Answer (score 2):

It means that if you have two functions $f(t)$ and $g(t)$, and you want to differentiate $y(t) = f(t)+g(t)$, then it's the same as differentiating $f$, differentiating $g$, and then add the two together:
$$
\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{df}{dt} + \frac{dg}{dt}
$$
This, of course, also work for $n$'th order derivatives.

There is another thing that is needed in order to call differentiation "linear", and that's the following: If your $y(t)$ is of the form $c\cdot y_0(t)$, where $c$ is a constant, then you can put the constant "outside" the differentiation:
$$
\frac{dy}{dt} = c\cdot \frac{dy_0}{dt}
$$

Comment: Ok.You have simply listed homogeniety and superposition.Give me an example where its not linear or is it always linear?

Comment: @muhammadmuheeb Differentiation is always linear, as long as the operations $+$ and $\cdot$ makes sense in the codomain of the function. If the function gives real values, vectors, or something like that, then you're good to go. If your function gives points on the circle or something, then that's worse. There are exaples of operators that are not linear, the simplest one that I can think of is "add $1$ to your function value".